# ASP.NET MVC CSS classes on HTML.Controls

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I think I'm missing something relatively simple here, but I'm trying to find a way of applying a CSS class to my controls within my views. I'm using the

`<%= Html.SubmitButton("Submit", "Edit Plot")%>`

style method of doing this. Short of putting divs around these elements and applying the styling, is there anyone way of getting access to the `CssClass` property that would be available in normal .NET?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out http://blog.veggerby.dk/2008/11/19/aspnet-mvc-htmlhelper-methods-and-css-class/, it is simply:

```
<% = Html.TextBox("name", null, new{ @class = "required"})  %>
```